# SQL display extra column in output

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm trying to do a mySQL query whereby a & b need to be distinct, but I also want to show column c in the output. c has no bearing on the query - its more like a marker/index that makes the results of a, b make more sense.

SQL:

```
select distinct a, b
from tbl
```

Not sure how to force c as 1st column into o/p of above query.

Any ideas?

Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a, b, MAX(c) AS c
FROM tbl
GROUP BY a, b
```

While MySql will let you exclude columns from the `GROUP BY` that aren't in an aggregate function because of their "[extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)", it would be better to wrap the value in an aggregate such as `MAX()` in order to make the query portable and the results deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't mentioned in your question which `c` must be in result set then you can try this:

```
select c, a, b
from tbl
group by a, b
```